# gevent control greenlets with events

Tags: python, events, concurrency, gevent

Let say I have an Event() coming in and there are a X number of greenlets waiting for the event. When those waiting greenlets are done I want to do a Publish()

How do I know when to publish?

schematic:

```
event.set() -> X number event.wait() -> finally publish the current state.
```

How do I make sure that all greenlets who wait() are done before I do a publish?

I think putting all the waiting greenlets in a Group
and do a group.join() could work.

```
import gevent
from gevent.pool import Group
from gevent.event import Event
import random

incoming = Event()

group = Group()

def test_wait(x):
    gevent.sleep(random.random() * 3)
    print 'test %s' % (x)

def publish():
    print 'published' 


for x in range(int(random.random() * 20)):
    group.spawn(test_wait, x)


def event_setter():
    incoming.set()
    gevent.sleep(0)                                                                                                                      
    publish()


event_setter()
```

Gevent.sleep(0) works if there is no sleep in the test_wait.
How can I be sure all waiting greenlets have ended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all greenlets into a list and call `gevent.joinall(your_greenlets)`. The [documentation](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.joinall) is a bit spare, but there's an [example](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example).

Answer (score 0):

If you use group.join() instead of gevent.sleep(0) in event_setter(), you can see the desired result, like this:

```
Group size: 10
test 6
test 9
test 3
test 7
test 1
test 4
test 0
test 5
test 2
test 8
published
```

"Group size: 10"  printed by the line: print "Group size: %d" % (len(group),)